# Is NSUserDefault thread safe?

Tags: objective-c, arrays, thread-safety

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/Reference/Reference.html says it is

> ...should prevent users from editing that preference by disabling any
>   appropriate controls.
>
> The **NSUserDefaults class is thread-safe.** Persistence of NSURL and
>   file reference URLs...

This long discussion says it isn't

http://www.cocoabuilder.com/archive/cocoa/155227-nsuserdefaults-thread-safety.html

So which one is right? Also why the difference of opinion.

Comment: Keep in mind that the discussion you posted a link to is from 2006, so it's entirely possible that NSUserDefaults has become thread safe since then.

Comment: Anyone knows more about history? Perhaps NSUserDefaults is thread safe but it's singleton is not. That kind of thing.

Comment: Unless you have **recent** evidence to suggest otherwise, I'd guess the docs are probably correct in saying that the class is thread safe. Whether it's a custom instance or the `standardUserDefaults` instance (I assume that's what you mean by "singleton"), they are all ultimately instances of the same class and will either be thread safe or not.

Comment: NSUserDefaults has gone through many implementations over the years. The thread-safety guarantees have been getting steadily better with each one, it's in quite good shape in recent OS releases.

Answer (score 77, accepted):

The Apple iOS 5.1 and OS X 10.7 documentation say that it is thread-safe; therefore it is thread-safe.

Comment: look at the date of the discussion. It is awfully outdated.

Comment: If you have a function that reads and writes back to the same key, do you think that would be thread safe? How misleading.

Answer (score 49):

Speaking for 10.10 and iOS8 if you looking into the implementation you'll find that `-[NSUserDefaults setObject:forKey:]` is calling `__CFPreferencesSetAppValueWithContainer`, which will eventually end up in `+[CFPrefsSource withSourceForIdentifier:user:byHost:container:perform:]`. This method is using a `pthread_mutex_t` to lock the access to the dictionary containing the values.

**So NSUserDefaults is thread safe.**

Comment: how to see the implementation anyway?

Comment: Reading the assembly using Hopper Disassembler (or Xcode)

Comment: You can also see this by running NSUserDefaults methods a few thousand times in a loop and checking out the performance profiler tool in instruments which captures the stack frames

Answer (score 0):

Not to mislead people, it's easy to write thread unsafe code. Reading and Writing to a particular key might be thread safe in isolation, but if you have a function that reads and then writes it back to same key, that is definitely not thread safe.

Example:

```
- (void)writeToNSUserDefaults:(NSObject *)obj
                       forKey:(NSString *)key {
    NSArray *array = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] arrayForKey:key];
    
    if (array == nil) {
        array = [[NSArray alloc] init];
    }
    
    NSMutableArray *mutableArray = [array mutableCopy];
    
    [mutableArray addObject:obj];
    
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:mutableArray forKey:key];
}
```

To make it thread safe you'll need to use `@synchronized`:

```
- (void)writeToNSUserDefaults:(NSObject *)obj
                       forKey:(NSString *)key {
    @synchronized (self) {
        NSArray *array = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] arrayForKey:key];
        
        if (array == nil) {
            array = [[NSArray alloc] init];
        }
        
        NSMutableArray *mutableArray = [array mutableCopy];
        
        [mutableArray addObject:obj];
        
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:mutableArray forKey:key];
    }
}
```