# How to retrieve UseDefault saved data from another ViewController

Tags: ios, swift

I have 2 ViewControllers, one displays the UI and the 2nd one displays a segmented control used as a settings button.  Im using the below code to save the segmented control state:

```
UserDefaults.standard.set(selectorLabel.selectedSegmentIndex, forKey: "stateSelected")
```

I then retrieve that usedefault on the viewdidload method:

```
if let value = UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "stateSelected"){  
            let selectedIndex = value as! Int  
            selectorLabel.selectedSegmentIndex = selectedIndex  
        }
```

So far this works as intended and the state of the segmented controlled is loaded properly each app load.

The segmented control has two text titles - one is "LBs & INs" and the second is "KGs & CMs".

How would I save those two segmented control text titles as UserDefaults and then call them on the first ViewController to set two labels on the viewdidload?

Comment: You should not be storing the titles in user defaults. That makes localization much more difficult.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define a model to represent data you want to store and restore:

```
struct SegmentedControlState: Codable {
    let selectedIndex: Int
    let titles: [String]
}
```

Initialize a model, encode and store it somewhere (like user default):

```
func saveState(of segmentedControl: UISegmentedControl) {
    let state = SegmentedControlState(
        selectedIndex: segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex,
        titles: (0..<segmentedControl.numberOfSegments).map { segmentedControl.titleForSegment(at: $0) ?? ""})

    let plist = try! PropertyListEncoder().encode(state)

    UserDefaults.standard.set(plist, forKey: "SegmentedControlState")

    //UserDefaults.standard.synchronize() //if targeting older iOS
}
```

for restoring, you should reverse the order like this:

```
func loadState(on segmentedControl: UISegmentedControl) {
    guard let plist = UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "SegmentedControlState") as? Data else { return }

    let state = try! PropertyListDecoder().decode(SegmentedControlState.self, from: plist)

    for element in state.titles.enumerated() {
        segmentedControl.setTitle(element.element, forSegmentAt: element.offset)
    }

    segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex = state.selectedIndex
}
```

usage:

```
// store `selectorLabel` data
saveState(of: selectorLabel)

// restore `selectorLabel` data
loadState(on: selectorLabel)
```

**Note that** it is not a good idea to store data like this to `userdefaults` at all. If you want to access some data from anywhere in code, you should follow **singleton pattern** and define your own singleton instance instead of standard userdefault.

Comment: `UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()` is deprecated and no longer necessary.

Comment: Also - correct me if I'm wrong, but I believe UserDefaults is totally [thread safe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10864482/is-nsuserdefault-thread-safe) on its own. Therefore, don't think you need to implement the singleton pattern for this.

Comment: Correct! but `UserDefaults` is for user's defaults, not for UI states. Just because `UserDefaults` is a singleton and can be accessed from anywhere, doesn't mean it used to be for any kind of shared data.

Comment: I agree! But then if that's the case, I might amend your last statement here. You say one should follow the singleton pattern for accessing UserDefaults from anywhere - but you must actually mean one should follow the singleton pattern for shared data / UI states across the app. In this case, your `SegmentedControlState` `struct` should be accessed from a singleton to make it thread safe.

Comment: I think it's because of language misunderstanding. Actually `it` refers to the custom data storage. I updated my last statement for better clarification. Thanks for mentioning that.

Comment: Ah, makes sense. No problem!

Answer (score 0):

Just store the value as a string, instead of an integer index.

```
UserDefaults.standard.set(selectorLabel.titleForSegment(at: selectorLabel.selectedSegmentIndex), forKey: "stateSelected")
```

And then to retrieve:

```
UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "stateSelected")
```

**EDIT:** @rmaddy is correct above - you should ideally be storing an index value like you're already doing, and then using an array to determine which title the index refers to (cleaner than just using a title as a reference). You could make this array global so you can access from anywhere, if you must.

```
segmentedControlTitles: [String] = ["LBs & INs", "KGs & CMs"]
```

And then call by

```
let index = UserDefaults.standard.integer(forKey: "stateSelected")
let title = segmentedControlTitles[index]
```

Comment: I can call userdefaults from any ViewController, right?

Comment: Yes, `UserDefaults` is persistent storage. You can access it from anywhere.

Comment: im kind of confused now.  Would i set that global array and then save them to userdefualts and then call it from the first VC viewdidload?  Basically, i need to set a label on the first VC to the saved index title of the segmented control

Comment: You could do one of two things. 1. Define the array as a constant somewhere - and always keep it as a reference to lookup the title for the current index, and just save the index in UserDefaults. Or 2. Save both the index and the title separately (with two different keys - e.g. `"stateSelectedIndex"` and `"stateSelectedTitle"`)